# Commands in acronym text - makeglossaries errors

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I have the following acronyms defined:

```
%% ACRONYM CONFIG
\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist,nomain,acronym,nopostdot,toc=false]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{} % remove the unwanted blank page
\usepackage{glossary-mcols} % two column
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{} % no dots
\makeglossaries
\glsaddall

\newacronym{I2C}{I\textsuperscript{2}C}{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\newacronym{I2S}{I\textsuperscript{2}S}{Inter-IC Sound}
```

`makeglossaries thesis` prints the following error:

```
WARNING: Would replace complete index key by empty string, ignoring
     #<ordrule-regexp: '\\[a-zA-Z@]+ *' => '' :again NIL :only-at-start NIL>
**Warning:**

Sort key required for entries only containing command names.
Attempting to determine which entries have problem sort keys.
Parsing 'thesis.acn'
2 problematic entries found:

Label: 'I2C'. Sort value : 'I2C'
(Try adding sort={I2C} to the definition.)
Label: 'I2S'. Sort value : 'I2S'
(Try adding sort={I2S} to the definition.)
```

The `sort={I2S}` piece looks like what you would use in a glossary entry, but I have acronyms. Where do I put it?

I tried the following, but it didn't do anything:

```
\newacronym[sort={I2C}]{I2C}{I\textsuperscript{2}C}{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\newacronym[sort={I2S}]{I2S}{I\textsuperscript{2}S}{Inter-IC Sound}
```

Answer (score 0):

okay this is strange, but the solution was to delete the .acn, .acr and .xdy files, rerun pdflatex, rerun makeglossaries (now ok), and again pdflatex

I don't understand what happened, but it works now.

It seems this was correct:

```
\newacronym[sort={I2C}]{I2C}{I\textsuperscript{2}C}{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\newacronym[sort={I2S}]{I2S}{I\textsuperscript{2}S}{Inter-IC Sound}
```